# Word for putting a Y between every X

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I have a series of things...

XXX

...and I'm putting something else between each one:

XYXYX

Is there a verb for this? For example, between every workweek (X) there is a weekend (Y). Possible sentence: "Workweeks are _____ed with/by weekends."

The closest word I came up with is *intersperse*, but this seems to have a connotation of haphazardness or randomness (Oxford definition: to "scatter among or between other things; place here and there"). "Workweeks are interspersed with weekends" suggests a certain randomness to the occurrence of weekends, whereas I want to convey that a Y has been consistently placed between every X. Is there a word for this?

Comment: Workweeks are alternated with weekends

Comment: One or more Y is **inserted** in the sequence.

Comment: I get the X and Y example, but why the need to explain what a weekend is? It is like saying "between every sleep I am awake".

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thanks, but I'm looking for something more specific than "inserted." The workweek/weekend example was only for illustration as an example of a Y placed between every X.

Comment: I think you need a different sample sentence. Workweeks are *segmented* by weekends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the word I was looking for: **interleave**.

> 1. (transitive) To insert (pages, which are normally blank) between the pages of a book.
> 2. (transitive) To intersperse (something) at regular intervals between the parts of a thing or between items in a group.

Source: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interleave)

This has the connotation I was looking for: that of interspersing a Y between every X (as in definition 1: a blank page between every page of a book).

Comment: This doesn't sound idiomatic for non-concrete entities. And there are just three Google hits for the more general "days are interleaved". None for "weeks are interleaved". If you're going to ask-and-answer-immediately, make sure you do _all_ the necessary research first.

Answer (score 0):

The verb demarcate means mark a separation, draw a boundary, set a limit. Use **[demarcated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demarcated)** as a precise and decisive word for *marked at set points*.

> The Southern plantation home had a formal entrance and shuttered windows demarcated by potted cypress trees.

*Workweeks are demarcated with weekends*.

For simply closed-in at both ends, use [**bracketed**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bracket).

> To give my boss choices, I bracketed my target projection by both optimistic and pessimistic estimates.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, is the solid word "workweek" the preferred term? The phrase "working week" is used far more often.

You could use singular nouns and say "After each working week there is a weekend". Or, if you need plurals and a verb, you could say "Working weeks alternate with weekends".